# trying to accept a grade(note) that is over 60% and then get the average of all the grade for a certain person

Tags: sql, count, mismatch

This code `use Personne

```
insert into [dbo].[Note] ( noPersonne,cours,note)
values (25,'Math',65)

insert into personnes(nom,prenom)
values('Mark','anthony')

alter table personnes
alter column prenom varchar(50)

select* from personnes
select*from Note


use personne
alter PROCEDURE ajoutNote ( @noPersonne int,
@cours varchar(30),
@note int
)
AS

BEGIN TRAN
    IF @note>=60
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO note (noPersonne, cours, note)
        VALUES      (@noPersonne, @cours, @note) 
        BEGIN
            PRINT ('la note a ete rentrer avec succes')
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @moyenne INT;

                    SET @moyenne = (SELECT AVG(note.note) AS moyenne 
                                    FROM note
                                    WHERE nopersonne=@nopersonne)

                    BEGIN
                        PRINT @moyenne
                        --set @idPersonne=(select nopersonne from Note)
                        --set @Courso=(select cours from Note)

                        --select avg(Note.note) from Note 
                        --where noPersonne=@idpersonne and  cours=@Courso
                    END
                END
        END
        SAVE TRAN f4
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END



GO

exec ajoutNote 25,'Math',75


select *from personnes
select*from Note'
```

gives me this : 
(1 row affected)
la note a ete rentrer avec succes
63
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure ajoutNote, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 55]
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 6, current count = 7.

Completion time: 2020-02-20T14:40:26.6563562-05:00

i just want to get rid of the mistake the code does what i want.

Comment: If you count the `begin` and `end`, there are 6 `begin` and 5 `end`. You need 1 more `end`. Not sure why you need so many inside the transaction. But I'm assuming that if you add 1 more `end` at the end of the proc, that should fix the error.

Comment: @SS_DBA The very first `BEGIN` is actually a `BEGIN TRAN` with no `COMMIT TRAN`. So either OP needs a `COMMIT TRAN` at the end, or the proc needs to be rewritten to remove the extraneous `BEGIN...END` blocks.

Comment: @digital.aaron Thanks for that! Good solid answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many `BEGIN...END` statements, and they seem to be overlapping as well. You also start a transaction but never commit it (`SAVE TRAN` only creates a savepoint, it doesn't actually commit the transaction). You don't have any error checking logic, so I don't see a need for an explicit `ROLLBACK TRAN` command. If the transaction fails, it will be rolled back.

So cleaning up the code and removing unneeded `BEGIN...END` blocks, I come up with this:

```
USE personne
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE ajoutNote 
( 
    @noPersonne int
    ,@cours varchar(30)
    ,@note int
)
AS
IF @note>=60
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION f4

        INSERT INTO note 
        (
            noPersonne
            ,cours
            ,note
        )
        VALUES
        (
            @noPersonne
            ,@cours
            ,@note
        ) 

        PRINT ('la note a ete rentrer avec succes')

        DECLARE @moyenne INT;

        SELECT @moyenne = AVG(note.note) 
        FROM note
        WHERE nopersonne = @nopersonne

        PRINT @moyenne

    COMMIT TRANSACTION f4

END
```

Notice I move the check of `IF @note>=60` outside the transaction. If `@note` is ever less than `60`, we don't even need to attempt the transaction.

EDIT: After looking over your code again, you may be able to add `COMMIT TRAN` at the end of the proc to remove the error without modifying the rest of the logic of the proc, specifically the `SAVE TRAN f4`. I don't know your requirements, so I don't know if this technique is appropriate for your proc. But if you just add the `COMMIT`, your proc will look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ajoutNote 
( 
    @noPersonne int
    ,@cours varchar(30)
    ,@note int
)
AS
BEGIN TRAN
    IF @note>=60
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO note (noPersonne, cours, note)
        VALUES      (@noPersonne, @cours, @note) 
        BEGIN
            PRINT ('la note a ete rentrer avec succes')
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @moyenne INT;

                    SET @moyenne = (SELECT AVG(note.note) AS moyenne 
                                    FROM note
                                    WHERE nopersonne=@nopersonne)

                    BEGIN
                        PRINT @moyenne
                        --set @idPersonne=(select nopersonne from Note)
                        --set @Courso=(select cours from Note)

                        --select avg(Note.note) from Note 
                        --where noPersonne=@idpersonne and  cours=@Courso
                    END
                END
        END
        SAVE TRAN f4
        RETURN;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN 
        ROLLBACK TRAN
    END

COMMIT TRAN
```